# Need to a 'like' comparision

Tags: c#, regex

Need help to find C# code to do a SQL-type like search (case insensitive)
could you please help me with regex code for this. Pattern and test candidates are both user input

`*` could be anywhere. so pattern could be .T*S.com

*e.g.*

```
Pattern = *.test.com
Test Candidate1 = abc.test.com                   Result = Pass
Test Candidate2 = abc.tESt.com                   Result = Pass
Test Candidate3 = abc.itest.com                  Result = FAIL
```

Comment: Regex can handle that, but so can a simple case insensitive string comparison in this case.

Comment: How does `*.test.corp` match `abc.test.com`?

Comment: I don't see how any of these can pass.

Comment: What kind of help do you need?

Comment: @mawburn No, he just edited his question to fix the typo I pointed out. I understand what he's trying to do.

Comment: [`(?i)[^.]+\.test\.com`](http://regex101.com/r/cM0pC1/1)

Comment: yeah.. could you please help me with regex code for this.. 

pattern and test candidates are both user input

Comment: Does `abc.test.comfoo` match?

Answer (score 2):

In case the `*` is at the front you can use [`String.EndsWith()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith(v=vs.110).aspx).

Like

```
"abc.test.com"
    .EndsWidth(".test.com", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

returns `true`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to go the regex route and the candidate always ends with .test.com you can get rid of the `*` in your pattern and then check with `EndsWith`:

```
if (candidate.EndsWith(pattern, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    // you have a match
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the regex, the pattern is need to be:

```
public bool IsMatch(string s,string pattern)
{
     return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(s, pattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
string pattern = ".*\.test\.com"
Console.WriteLine(IsMatch("abc.test.com",pattern).ToString()); //PASS
Console.WriteLine(IsMatch("abc.tESt.com",pattern).ToString()); //PASS
Console.WriteLine(IsMatch("abc.itest.com",pattern).ToString()); //FAIL
```